# how to use python to dig cname with @

Tags: python, dns, dig

I found this bit of code:

```
  1 import dns.resolver
  2 answer=dns.resolver.query("google.com", "A")
  3 for data in answer:
  4         print data.address
```

And it works great but what i'm looking to do is this :
dig +noall +answer google.com @ipAddress  (where ip address is a different location globally) Then make a loop to pass in different global ip addresses.

Not sure how to get dns.resolve.query to query @ different ip addresses.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ah figured it out here's how to change the ns

```
  1 import dns.resolver
  2
  3 my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
  4 my_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
  5
  6 answer=my_resolver.query("example.com", "A")
  7 for data in answer:
  8         print data.address
  9
```